# Chrome: Is there a keyboard shortcut for going back in a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome

Say I opened a link from Google search results within the same tab. Now I want to keep my newly-opened website there and go back to my search results in a separate new tab. Intuitively it could be *Ctrl+Backspace* but apparently this isn't the case.

Comment: So, basically, you want a new tab that is one page back in the current tab's history? No, there is nothing like that built in, but it would be pretty easy to write a userscript to do that.

Comment: @EdCottrell Could you give me a pointer to writing a userscript? I've never heard of that.

Comment: You might want to read [the information on this how-to](https://github.com/OpenUserJs/OpenUserJS.org/wiki/Userscript-beginners-HOWTO); it's not mine, but it appears to be reasonably accurate and complete. You will need to install the Tampermonkey plugin to run userscripts in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ctrl+ click the back arrow on the browser. But I don't think there's a purely keyboard combination like ctrl+backspace. At least not from my research.